# best way to check if an object is null or empty string in r

Tags: r

I want to check if a variable is `''` or 'NULL'. I did below:

```
x =NULL #or ''

if(is.null(x) || x=='') {
    print('nothing')
} else {
    print(x)
}
```

My question is what is the best way to check this condition? I feel like there is some better way to do this...

Answer (score 4):

Rather than check if it is NULL or an empty character string it might make more sense to check if it has a non-zero length and is a string which is not empty.  Then the first leg of the `if` will handle the primary case and the `else` leg will handle the less common case which seems easier to follow than the other way around.

```
if (length(x) && nzchar(x)) x else NA
```

Comment: One drawback is that `nzchar(NA) && length(NA)` evaluates to `TRUE`. I know this isn't want the OP wanted.

Comment: But that is a different condition, not the one asked for in the question.

Comment: Using `any(nzchar(x))` might be safer; in some circumstances R complains when you give it a vector of logicals to test.

Comment: It depends on what is wanted. If a scalar is expected and a vector is given it would be better to raise an error.